# How to combine child routes with wrapper component in standalone?

Tags: angular

With modules, i have:

```
[
  {
    path:'',
    component: IntroPageComponent
  },
  {
    path:'app',
    component:LayoutWrapperComponent,
    children:[
     {
       path:'products',
       loadChildren: 'lazyLoadedModule'
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

`LayoutWrapperComponent` has header, footer and `router-outlet` for content area.
I want to lazy load components into that `router-outlet`.

On the other hand, for base route I want to show `IntroPageComponent` that doesnt have header/footer.

I cant find anything about this situation in docs for standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standalone and modular applications, lazy modules and lazy routes are loaded the same way using `loadChildren`.

Examples:

https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback#description.
https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-many-routes-at-once

```
[
  {
    path:'',
    component: IntroPageComponent
  },
  {
    path:'app',
    component:LayoutWrapperComponent,
    children:[
     {
       path:'products',
       loadChildren: () =>
          import('./lazy-loaded.module').then(
            (m) => m.LazyLoadedModule
          ),
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: oh...is there anything about this in docs that I have missed? (ashamed)

Comment: For standalone and modular applications, lazy modules and lazy routes are loaded the same way using loadChildren.
Examples: https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback#description.

Comment: yeah, that example still doesn't show wrapper component case.